# null returned when I copied string with char pointer

Tags: c

I tried copying string with char pointers, and the program gave me nothing and I have no idea...

Please let me know problems of my code.

```
int main() {
    char *a = "helloworld.txt";
    char *b = malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );

    while(*a!='\0') {
        *b++=*a++;
    }
    *b = '.';
    b++;
    *b = '\0';

    printf("string: %s\n", b);
}
```

the result was:

```
string:
```

Comment: `*b = '\0'; printf("string: %s\n", b);` : `b` point to `'\0'`. The address of the head of the string you need to keep.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes so I tried printf("string: %s\n", &b[0] ) and it still gave me null string. where should I fix to print string without help of another string pointer ?

Comment: @devsy: `&b[0]` is completely equivalent to `b` (at least when `b` is already pointer), so that change did nothing.

Comment: @TimČas okay then how about print b-15? which supposed to be the start point of "helloworld.txt.b" ... ?

Comment: @devsy that will work, although it's not a very flexible solution. Sometimes, you just don't know how many places to jump back. Creating a second pointer to the start of the `malloc`ed memory is the easiest approach

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Okay I checked that b-15 prints well and thanks to all of you guys!!!

Comment: you can use `b[index++]` instead of `*b++`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this:

```
int main() {
  char *a = "helloworld.txt";
  char *b = malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );
  char *c = b;                  // save pointer to allocated memory

  while(*a!='\0') {
    *b++=*a++;
  }
  *b = '.';
  b++;
  *b = '\0';                    // b points to the end of the constructed 
                                // string now

  printf("string: %s\n", c);    // use pointer saved before instead of b
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to print string b without help of c?

Comment: @devsy of course `b = &b[0]` doesn' work. `b = &b[0]` is  equivalent to `b = b;`.

Comment: _Is there any way to print string b without help of c?_ No there is no way. Once you have allocated memory with malloc, `b` points to that memory. If you modify `b` afterwords you "loose" that pointer.

Comment: @devsy `print b-15` works if the total length of the string is exacly 15, but how can you be sure that the length is 15 ? Modifying the "helloworld.txt" string would break your program.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments! it helped me a lot!

Comment: Yes I agree with that. I just wanted to clarify how the pointer works in memory and what I had to check was that _b-15 will go back 15 chars from the current pointer_ .. Definitely I won't use b-15 on real programs.. Thanks!!

Comment: You could print `b-strlen(a)-1`

Comment: @devsy You also need to save the original value of `b` so you can `free()` it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you say `printf("string: %s\n", b);` you are trying to print the string starting from `b` but `*b = '\0'`. So no wonder empty string.

1. Save the pointer `b` to a `temp` pointer which we'll use to print the string as pointer `b` keeps increasing in `while` loop and we loose track of starting of string. Or
2. Use `printf("string: %s\n", (b - (strlen(a)+1));` as suggested by @Barmar in comments.

---

Also how are you sure about `b` pointing to a valid memory location after `malloc`? This code is error-prone and may lead to `SegFault`.

Always check whether memory got allocated or not after `malloc, calloc etc.` by comparing the pointer with `NULL`

```
char *b = malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );
if(!b)
{
    printf("Memory not allocated!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation! :) !!

Answer (score 0):

The original issue is that you modify the pointer to the target-string. `b` points to the string terminator, thus the following `printf` will just see an empty string. Use a temp pointer to increment.

But that incrementing has other - more severe (in terms of program stability) issues: You change the only pointer to the allocated object. Thus you cannot `free` it anymore.

In general you should `free` an allocated memory block once you don't need it anymore.

Also **always** check for errors reported by functions. `malloc` might fail, returning a *null pointer*. Dereferencing a *null pointer* is undefined behaviour. You don't want to encounter it!

Comment: Can I free blocks if I make pointer b point the original address with using b = b-15 (15 is used block nums for string 'helloworld.txt.b' )? does it still know the allocated size (which is 20) ????

Comment: or should I let the pointer only point to the originally allocated position?

Comment: @devsy: To say "thank you" please don't comment, but use the upvote button. Yes, you have to use the exactly same address you got from `malloc` & friends for `free`. From your questions I see you lack some basic understanding no offence. You will find the answers and many others you eventually will encounter in every good C book or tutorial. For now just remeber to call `free` once for **every** object you `malloc`ed. That includes `calloc` and `realloc(NULL, size)` (or similar). The pointer is that of the object, thus the same value you got from the allocation function. Also check for errors!

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(){

    char *str1;
    printf("\nEnter the string to be copied\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&*str1);
    copystr(&str1);
    getch();
    clrscr();

}


copystr(char **str1){
    char **str2;
    int i=0;
    while(**str1!='\0'){
         // printf("address if str1 %u ",*str1);
        *str2=*str1;
           printf("\n%c",**str2);
        (*str1)++;
        (*str2)++;
        i++;
        printf(" address of str2 %u ",*str2);
    }
    *str2=(*str2)-i;
    //  printf("%d",i);
    printf("\n%s",*str2);
}
```